# Como passar uma variável para outra página usando IONIC?

Tags: angularjs, ionic, framework

Olá, estou fazendo uma aplicação usando o framework IONIC e estou dificuldades em passar parâmetros para outra página.

Tenho a listagem de itens ( que são dados que estão vindo do banco de dados ) e em cada item tenho um botão "detalhes" que me leva para uma pagina com informações detalhadas. No caso queria que se se clicasse  no item1 iria para uma pagina com detalhes SOMENTE do item 1, ou seja, uma pagina que detalhe o item clicado.
Essa parte de levar o item clicado para uma nova pagina que eu não estou conseguindo.

abaixo estão os códigos:
schedule.html
schedule.ts
os-detalhes.html (aqui é a pagina quero imprimir os detalhes do item clicado)
os-detalhes.ts

```js
//schedule.ts


import { Component} from '@angular/core';

import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";

//import { ConferenceData } from '../../providers/conference-data';
import { UserData } from '../../providers/user-data';
import { OsDataProvider} from '../../providers/os-data/os-data';

import {OsDetalhesPage} from "../os-detalhes/os-detalhes";
//import {OsDetalhesPage} from "../os-detalhes/os-detalhes";




@Component({
  selector: 'page-schedule',
  templateUrl: 'schedule.html'
})
export class SchedulePage {
  username: string;
  nome_cliente: string;
    public lista_os = new Array<any>();
  //result: any; 
  //users: any[];
  //fullName = [];
  //options: any;
  //local: any;
  //public location: any;
 // public fullDetails: any[];
  public osDetails: any;
  public userDetails: any;
  data: any;
  //userPostData = {"email":"","name":"","user_id":""};
 // login: UserOptions = { username: '', password: '' };
  //userID = { codtecnico: '' };
 // responseData: any;
  //submitted = false;
  // @ViewChild(InfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: InfiniteScroll;
  
  rootPage: any = SchedulePage;

  constructor(
    //public alertCtrl: AlertController, 
    public nav: NavController, 
    public userData: UserData,
    public OSData: OsDataProvider,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    //public loginData: UserData,
   // public authService: AuthService,
   public storage: Storage,
   // public platform: Platform,
   // public geolocation: Geolocation
    //private geoposition: Geoposition,
    //private diagnostic: Diagnostic,
    //public toastCtrl: ToastController
  ) {
    this.storage.get('userData').then((data:any) => {
      const dados = JSON.parse(data);
      //this.lista_os = dados;
     //console.log(this.lista_os);
      if (dados) {
        this.userDetails = dados.userid[0].userData;
        this.lista_os = dados.userid[1].OSData;
        console.log(this.lista_os = dados.userid[1].OSData);
        //console.log(this.osDetails = dados.userid[1].OSData[0]);
        //this.userID.codtecnico = dados.userData.user_id;
      }
    });     
    
   
    
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.getUsername();
    this.getNomeCliente();
  }

  
    getUsername()  {
      this.userData.getUsername().then((name) => {
        this.username = name;
        //console.log('Name',name);
      });
    };

    getNomeCliente(){
      this.OSData.getNomeCliente().then((name) => {
        this.nome_cliente = name;
      });
    
    };


    abrirDetalhes(){
        this.navCtrl.push(OsDetalhesPage);
    };

  
 }
  
    

//---------------------------------------------------------------//

 
//os-detalhes.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the OsDetalhesPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-os-detalhes',
  templateUrl: 'os-detalhes.html',
})
export class OsDetalhesPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad OsDetalhesPage');
  }



}
```

```html
<!-- Schedule.html -->

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>OS</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div padding >




    <ion-card  *ngFor="let e of lista_os">



      <ion-card-content>

          <b> Id: </b> {{e.id_os}}<br>
          <b> Nome Cliente: </b>{{e.nome_cliente}} <br>
          <b> Data: </b>{{e.data_agenda}} <br>


      </ion-card-content>
      <button ion-button block (click)="abrirDetalhes()">Detalhes</button>
      
    </ion-card>



  </div>
</ion-content>




<!-- os-detalhes.html           -----------------------------             -->

<!--
  Generated template for the OsDetalhesPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Ordem de Serviço Detalhada</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <ion-card-content>

    <b> Id: </b> {{id_os}}<br>
    <b> Nome Cliente: </b>{{nome_cliente}} <br>
    <b> Data Agendada: </b>{{data_agenda}} <br>
    <b> Período do Dia: </b> <br>
    <b> Prioridade: </b><br>



  </ion-card-content>


</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passe as variáveis assim:

```
this.navCtrl.push('Pagina', {
    data: variavel,
    data2: valorQualquer,
    ...
});
```

E então, na sua Página que irá ser aberta, você pega as variáveis assim:

```
variavel = navParams.get('data');
valorQUalquer = navParams.get('valorQualquer');
```

Comment: Mas como fazer de uma forma dinâmica? Pois tenho um array de informações, e na view eu dou um foreach, como vai reconhecer que o tal dado de id selecionado vai ser passado? Ou seja, se eu clico no item com **id =1** como que no **this.navCtrl()** vai reconhecer que o **id = 1?**

Answer (score 0):

Na sua chamada html `abrirDetalhes()` coloque o valor como parâmetro `abrirDetalhes(1)`  (este valor `1` será dinâmico), já no seu TS coloca ele no parâmetro da função `abrirDetalhes(id){`